# how to embed a true type font within a postscript file

Tags: types, fonts, postscript, cups

I have a cross platform app and for my Linux and Mac versions it generates a postscript file for printing reports and then prints them with CUPS. It works for simple characters and images but I would like to have the ability to embed a true type font directly into the postscript file. Does anyone know how to do this?? 
Also I can encode simple ascii characters but I'm not sure how to encode any characters beyond the usual a-z 0-9, things like foreign characters with accents.

Answer (score 9):

In order to embed a TrueType font in a Postscript document, you will first need to convert it to a Type 42 font. This conversion turns the font into postscript code.
There are several small utilities for doing this conversion, or you can read
the [Type 42 specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/font/pdfs/5012.Type42_Spec.pdf) and write
your own code for it.

Embedding Type 1 fonts is a lot easier. Linux ships with a large set of Type 1 fonts, and so does OS X if you have X11 installed. Generating PDF instead is also an option you may want to look into, since PDF can embed TrueType fonts directly.

Answer (score 5):

Postscript fonts come with widely varying encodings, so if you want to reliably
print iso-8859-1 characters you need to reencode the font in your postscript
program.

[PostScript FAQ - How to print accented characters](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PostScript_FAQ#How_to_print_accented_characters.3F)